# java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long firebase realtime

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having this error does anyone know how to fix?

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

LOGCAT

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
        at com.appcom.Cassino$1.onDataChange(Cassino.java:68)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

CODE /LINE ERROR

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    long v= (long) dataSnapshot.getValue(); // This is the line of error
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(v,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mQnATimer.setText("time : "+millisUntilFinished/1000);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Please post database structure

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a pretty straightforward problem. However, I cannot tell for sure without seeing your actual data structure.

From the logcat, it looks like you are getting a `String` value and while you are trying to cast it to the `long` you are getting an exception.

I would recommend doing the following in that case.

```
Long v = Long.parseLong((String) dataSnapshot.getValue());
```

If the `String` does not have a valid `Long`, then it should throw another exception though. However, as I said, it is difficult to understand the exact problem without seeing your database structure with some sample data.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

if your result is a `long` string like the following, you have to use `long.parseLong` to convert. it can not directly to Long object.

```
String str = "21111";
long num = Long.parseLong(str);
```

The way you used only supports Parent to a SubClass object.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase considers the values without double quotes as long (“8” as String & 8 as Long). So make sure you are having String data with double quotes in your Firebase database.
Also, use `.parseLong()` to convert.